# Is the a way to make ALLOWED_HOSTS accept new domains dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, django, dns, middleware

I want to let users connect their domains to my site.

For example, a user has bought example.com (the domain) and wants that when someone types example.com in the browser, what the browser shows is my app. I have everything configured and working except for the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting. If I add manually the domain to my ALLOWED_HOSTS it works. But, in production server, users will be creating this connections at anytime, I can't be adding this lines manually and restarting the server.

Is there a different way of achievings this without making

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]`

If there is no other way, I'm not sure which is the safest way to check `request.get_host()` in a middleware. If someone could guide me, I'd be eternally thankfull.

I hope I explained myself good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the best way was allowing everything on django ALLOWED_HOSTS, and then configuring correctly the server in production, in my case Nginx and gunicorn to only allow what I want.

Comment: What's the solution ? Make `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Comment: Yes, is not Django who should control this. It should be the server. In my case was an Nginx server where I allowed the correct domains.